# How to repair a wire in a light switch box

Tags: lighting, dimmer-switch

In attempting to install a dimmer switch, I managed to snap a wire in my light switch, by not realising when I was tightening it it was pushing on the wire. What would be the best approach to fixing it be, or would I be better calling out a professional?[image]

Comment: If you tug gently can you get more cable in the box?

Comment: Nah, I tried that, nothing came through unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

I can't see the clamp on the NM cable is it plastic or metal? If metal there is probably a screw on the outside you may be able to pull the Phillips screws(s) holding the box in place and move the box to gain access. If plastic you can break It and try, replacing the clamp with a raco "insider" it is a clamp that installs from inside the box quick and easy compared to other types. It looks to short to make a splice,  sometimes you have to open a wall when this happens hopefully you can get enough slack to splice in the box.